# facebook login blocking my webserver port 80 443

Tags: facebook, sdk, webserver

i am trying to make a app like nametests and Meaoww in which i am using JS facebook SDK to generate profile picture of the user and then redirect the user to specific page to generate a page according to the post.
i am using example given by facebook where

```
function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
     //code to redirect on successful login
    });
```

Everything works fine the script is running correctly.
But after sometime i get a notification from my web hosting that i am phishing and the code is malware it blocks my 443 and 80 ports and deletes my script.

**I want to if this is wrong implementaion of javaSDK or this is some issue with my web sever. My facebook app was in not published and i was using it with the help of testers and admin only.
PS: my hosting server is HOSTGATOR**

Comment: Sounds like you should ask Hostgator

Comment: has anyone faced issue like this?